# curl - load only new file from server (improvement)

Tags: bash, shell, api, http, curl

My question is if there is a better possibility to load a file from a server (API), only if it is newer than the local file. The file on the server is updated 2 times a day (about 6am and 6pm). The times of the update are always slightly different. Therefore, at this time the cronjob runs several times to check whether there is a new file or not. To save traffic, it should only load the file when it is newer than my old file locally. 
To do so: I check the HTTP code (200=new file downloaded; 304=no download).
When a new file is loaded, a script must be started, which processes the new file.
My idea so far:

```
$URL="http://abcdef.com/xxx/"
if [[ "$(curl $URL -z /path/to/file/file.dat -o /path/to/file/file.dat -s -L -w %{http_code})" == "200" ]]; then /path/to/script/script.prc; fi
```

Do you see any problems there? Are there ways to make it better?

Comment: @arco444 The OP indicated they already have a local copy of the file (from a previous fetch) and wants to have curl use that as a source for new-ness checking (that's what the `-z` argument is for.

Comment: Yes, it can be assumed that the file already exists.

Comment: The url needs to be the last argument doesn't it? Also you should quote `"$URL"` when you use it (generally always quote variables). You might want to use `-S` also to see error messages if any occur (that shouldn't conflict with the `-w` bit as the errors *should* go to `stderr`. You might also want `-f` to cause curl to fail on error instead of writing the error to the file (as that might confuse your next fetch attempt). If you do that it might be better to check for a modified file rather than the `200` return code.